# Angular - app initializer not being called

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11, initializer

I made several changes to an Angular 11 app and now there are a few things broken that I need to fix.
What I don't understand is why the app initializer that I defined is not being called at all.
The changes that I made shouldn't have impacted this, so I'd be grateful for some suggestions.
I did it exactly as written in the official documentation:

```js
function initApp(http: HttpBackend, settings: AppSettings): () => Observable<any> {
  console.log("INITIALIZING APP");
  var appInfoCall = () => new HttpClient(http).get<IApplicationInfo>(settings.appInfoApi).pipe(
  tap(data => {    
    console.log("APP INITIALIZATION COMPLETE");
    settings.appInfo = data;
  }));
  return appInfoCall; 
}
```

and the provider array in my app.module.ts:

```
...,
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: initApp,
  deps: [HttpBackend, HttpClient, AppSettings],
  multi: true
}
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

From the console output I can see that the `initApp` function isn't called at all.
Any ideas why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `initApp` is expected to be injected with two providers:

```js
function initApp(http: HttpBackend, settings: AppSettings): () => {
  ...
}
```

Modify the `APP_INITIALIZER` provider (`dep`) as:

```js
{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initApp,
    deps: [HttpBackend, AppSettings],
    multi: true,
}
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-doj5jc?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

---

**Reference**

[APP_INITIALIZER (Usage note)](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER#usage-notes)